# ui-sref on an input submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router

I'm new with Angularjs and I'm tyring to create a form with several views (using ui-router). Each view will contain different data for the form to be filled in, so when a view has been filled in, I don't want to just click on an anchor tag and continue to the next view. I would like it also to be like an input submit button which has some validation functions. How can I do it? This is what I have so far:

```
<section class="progress-bar">
<ul class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
  <a ui-sref=".first" ui-sref-active="active" class="btn list-group-item">First</a>
  <a ui-sref=".second" ui-sref-active="active" class="btn list-group-item">Second</a>
  <a ui-sref=".third" ui-sref-active="active" class="btn list-group-item">Third</a></ul>
</section>
<div>
  <form class="form" autocomplete="on" id="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </form>
```

The different views will have an `a` tag at the bottom which is the one I'd like to have some validation functions like an input submit button does:

```
<a ui-sref="form.second" class="btn btn-block btn-info" id="next1">Next</a>
```

And the final view will have the input submit:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit">
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I would like to use just the default validation that HTML5 provides. Just like an input submit does, without any extra functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-click` directive and bind it validation functions, and if `is_vaild is True` then redirect using `$state.go(state)`.

see : [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick); [$state](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've been struggling with it before giving up and posting again... could you please explain it with an example? This is what I tried:
`.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$state', 'formService', function($scope, $state, formService) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.goNext = function() {
        if ($('input').checkValidity()) {
            $state.go('form.second');
        }`
Did you mean that I should use checkValidity with your `is_valid`? If so, I see console errors saying that it's not a function